# Turning a list of lists or array into a nxn binary matrix

Tags: python

Ok so I need to take the following format of input file

```
5 5 12
1 1
1 2
2 1
2 3
3 1
3 2
3 4
4 2
4 4
1 2
2 3
5 5
```

and then turn it into a matrice where the left hand column represents the customer ID and the right hand column is the Item ID.

I can get Python to import the data however I'm struggling to manipulate it to the way I need.

and example of how I need the data would be:

```
          Item 1   Item 2  Item 3
Customer1:  1        2       0    
Customer2:  1        0       2
```

Here are the methods I've used to import the data:

```
def DataImport(filename):

    Data = []
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            Data.append([int(v) for v in line.split()])
    return Data
```

(incomplete)

```
def ImportData(filename):
    if filename == "history.txt":
        Option1 = np.loadtxt(filename, skiprows=1)
        CustomerID = np.loadtxt(filename, skiprows=1, usecols=(0,))
        ItemID = np.loadtxt(filename, skiprows=1, usecols=(1,))
        print(CustomerID)
        print(ItemID)
        print(Option1)
        Option11 = []
        for i in Option1:
            if i[i][0] == i[0]:
                Option11.append(i[0][1])
        print(Option11)
    else:
        Data = np.loadtxt(filename)

def ImportData(filename):
    rawdata = {}
    File = open(filename, "r")

    for line in File:
        rawdata[len(rawdata)+1] = line.rstrip("\n")
    File.close()
    print(rawdata)

def ImportData2(filename):
    with open(filename, newline='') as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=' ')
        next(reader)
        TRvalues = dict(reader)
    print(TRvalues)
```

I think the numpy method presents in a way that would be easiest to work with but I'm not sure how to get Python to itterate using the customerID as a key and then adding the values in the way previously mentioned.

I'm not sure if I've explained that well but I can answer questions if you need more clarification.

Comment: The first line of your example has `5 5 12` and all the rest only two entries. In general, do you want `Item 1   Item 2  Item 3` because the first line has three entries? And then the remainder would have `0` for item 3?  Your example input needs to be more clearly linked to the desired output. It is not obvious what you are looking for.

Comment: I *think* you are looking for a default value for columns not present in a line of input?

Comment: the first line is different data, sorry I forgot to mention that, it's everything after that first line.

Answer (score 0):

In principle I highly recommend using something like PANDAS (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html), especially

```
pandas.read_tabel
```

will generate a pandas data-frame that you can manipulate as you like.
However if you don't like that you can also just iterate by column rather than row by simply using

```
for row in matrix.T:
  instructions for rows...
```

rather then

```
for col in matrix:
  instructions for columns...
```

hope it helps.